# Thread safe InputStream in java

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream

How to create a Thread safe InputStream .During multithreaded operations the inputStream data gets corrupted,so how can i make my inputStream thread safe.will the following code work

```
public class SynchronizedInputStream  extends InputStream{

    private InputStream in;

    private SynchronizedInputStream( InputStream in ) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    /* ... method for every InputStream type to use */
    public  static InputStream createInputStream( InputStream in) {
        return new SynchronizedInputStream( in);
    }

    public static InputStream createPushBackInputStream(InputStream in,int BUFSIZE){
        return new SynchronizedInputStream(new PushbackInputStream(in,BUFSIZE));
    }

    /* Wrap all InputStream methods Used */

    public int read(){
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                return in.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int available() {
        synchronized( this ) {
            try {
                return in.available();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }


}
```

In the NANOHTTPD file

```
 public HTTPSession(TempFileManager tempFileManager, InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, InetAddress inetAddress) {
            this.inputStream=(PushbackInputStream) SynchronizedInputStream.createPushBackInputStream(inputStream);
        /*lines of code..........*/
        }
```

Then i call it like this

```
String Data = readStream(session.getInputStream());//session is HTTPSession
/*.....code....*/
private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        synchronized (in) {
            PushbackInputStream inputStream = (PushbackInputStream) in;
            StringBuffer outputBuffer = null;
            try {
                                 //Reading the InputStream Here
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                //error msg
            }
                return outputBuffer.toString();

        } 
    }
```

Comment: Probably. But you also have to make sure that no one else accesses the underlying `in` directly.

Comment: why would you multi-thread an inputstream?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish and where is your problem? It doesn't really make sense to me to try and synchronize around an input stream...

Comment: Wouldn't your application become very indeterministic? Multi-plexing an outputstream I can understand (for things like logs), but input? If anything, it would have to be at a higher (application-level) abstraction, where you read whole messages, not just bytes, no?

Comment: @Scary Wombat Actually m not directly multi Threading the input Stream but a Method of mine takes inputStream as argument and different threads acess that method.@Thilo inside the mentioned method i have syncronized "in".

Comment: @MattCoubrough as mentioned above Method of mine takes inputStream as argument and different threads acess that method.if its a single thread it works fine but for multithread data is corrupted.thats why i thought of syncronizing the input stream

Comment: If it was a singleton, then it would make a bit more sense.

Comment: @ScaryWombat actually i made it final.should i make it singleton?

Comment: @Thilo It will be used for getting the inputStream of IHTTPDsession.getInputStream().is it fine..?

Comment: Keeping it single-threaded, but switching to a Producer/Consumer pattern might make more sense. It's either that or making a thread-safe adapter that turns the InputStream into a BlockingQueue. Either way, realize that being able to make concurrent calls to read() won't magically make your code thread-safe; the threads still have to coordinate reads with each other, hence choosing a different approach.

Comment: If you are attempting to read a stream in multiple threads you have a design problem.  I would have one and only one thread read the stream and have that thread pass work to a thread pool if you want to multi-thread processing of the data read.  You should never need more than one thread to read a stream as this will read it as fast as possible and adding threads just adds complexity and confusion.

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you please tell me more about your approach and how should I  pass work to thread pool ...Sample code would be very Helpful if possible....

Comment: when you call `public  static InputStream createInputStream( InputStream in) {
        return new SynchronizedInputStream( in);
    }` your are trashing over the inputstream variable.  Nothing final about this.

Comment: I would start with the tutorial on ExecutorServices. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html  In fact I would read all the standard Java tutorials.

Comment: @PeterLawrey plz hav a look at the edits i hav made

Comment: @ManasL AFAIK the session will only have one thread calling it.  BTW don't use StringBuffer, it was replaces ten years ago by StringBuilder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that the class you have shown us is thread-safe, but the code that uses your class *probably won't be thread safe!!*

What you have implemented are operations that atomically read one character, and atomically test if there is something to be read.  The implementation of those operations is thread-safe, if (and only if) all threads use the same `SynchronizedInputStream` object to access a given `InputStream`, and nothing apart from your wrapper access the `InputStream` directly.

However, this most likely that this will not be sufficient to make your application's use of the streams thread-safe in the larger sense.

I expect that the "corruption" that you are observing is actually happening a higher level; e.g. two threads that are simultaneously making a sequence of `read` calls to read (say) messages are interleaving so that some bytes of a message are going to the wrong thread.  Assuming that that is your problem, then this does not fix it.  Your `read` method only locks the stream while a thread reads a single byte.  After unlocking, there is nothing to stop a different thread from reading the next byte.

There are a few ways to solve this.  For example"

- A simple way is to restructure your code only one thread *ever* reads from a given `InputStream`.  That thread reads the messages, and turns them into objects that can be handed off to others via a queue ... for example.
- Another way is to replace your wrapper class with one that reads an entire message atomically.  Don't extend `InputStream`.  Instead design your API in terms of the larger scale operations, and synchronize at that level of granularity.

**UPDATE**

Re the extra code you added.

It *looks like* only one thread (the current request thread) should ever be reading from the input stream.  If you are only using one thread there *should be* no issues with multi-threading or thread safety.  (And besides, that this the way that the nanoHTTPD code is designed to work.)

Supposing that there were multiple threads, your `synchronized (in) {` block in `readStream` *would normally* be sufficient to make the code thread-safe, provided that all all of the threads were using the same `in` object.

The problem is that your hacked `HttpSession` class is creating a separate `SynchronizedInputStream` for each "session", and THAT is what your code synchronizes on.  So if (somehow) two threads created `HttpSessions` objects using the same socket input stream, they would synchronize on different objects, and there would be no mutual exclusion.

But this is all conjecture.  So far, you have not demonstrated that there are multiple threads attempting to use the same input stream.

Answer (score 10):

You need to think about how it would make sense. Imagine more than one people are reading a magic book, which erases the character the first time anyone sees it. So only one person can read any given character. That's kind of how streams are.

This makes it really hard to read the book in a useful manner. When most naively done, each person will just get some random subset of the characters; not very useful information.

One straight forward solution is to let one read it and then copy it onto a book that doesn't erase characters when one reads it. This way everyone can read the book. In some situation, you don't need everyone to understand the book, and people can just work as long as they are given a sentence. In this case, the one reader can post each sentence to a queue from which everyone takes one sentence at a time.

Other approaches include having a buffer where each threads store the character they read, and then check each time if they can form a word, and if so emitting the word for downstream processing. For an example, see Netty's codec package (e.g. [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.goodwill-access/0.0.10/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/FrameDecoder.java)).

These approaches are however usually implemented on top of a stream rather than inside it. You could well have a stream that does these inside, but it will probably confuse people.